# How do I pass template parameters to a CRTP?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

In the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class CRTP
{
public:
};

template <int I, typename T>
class CRTPInt
{
public:
};

template <template <typename> class T>
class Derived : public T<Derived<T>>
{
public:
};

void main()
{
Derived<CRTP> foo;
Derived<CRTPInt<2>> foo2;
}
```

How do I write CRPTInt so I can pass in a templatized parameter that will then be continued in the Derived definition?

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CRTP pattern is typically used to enable **static polymorphism** and the ability to **mixin** (parametrized) behavior. To illustrate two alternatives, it's convenient to first define a general template

```
template
<
        typename Derived
>
class enable_down_cast
{
private:
        // typedefs

        typedef enable_down_cast Base;

public:
        Derived const* self() const
        {
                // casting "down" the inheritance hierarchy
                return static_cast<Derived const*>(this);
        }

        // write the non-const version in terms of the const version
        // Effective C++ 3rd ed., Item 3 (p. 24-25)
        Derived* self()
        {
                return const_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<Base const*>(this)->self());
        }

protected:
        // disable deletion of Derived* through Base*
        // enable deletion of Base* through Derived*
        ~enable_down_cast() = default; // C++11 only, use ~enable_down_cast() {} in C++98
};
```

Then you define an interface class template for the type of behavior that you want

```
template<typename FX>
class FooInterface
:
    // enable static polymorphism
    public enable_down_cast< FX >
{
private:
    // dependent name now in scope
    using enable_down_cast< FX >::self;

public:
    // interface
    void foo() { self()->do_foo(); }

protected:
    // disable deletion of Derived* through Base*
    // enable deletion of Base* through Derived*
    ~IFooInterface() = default; // C++11 only, use ~IFooInterface() {} in C++98/03
};
```

To get different implementations of this interface, simply define different classes that each derive from `FooInterface` with themselves as **curiously recurring template parameters**:

```
class FooImpl
:
    public FooInterface< FooImpl > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class FooInterface< FooImpl > ;
    void do_foo() { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
};

class AnotherFooImpl
:
    public FooInterface< AnotherFooImpl > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class FooInterface< AnotherFooImpl >;
    void do_foo() { std::cout << "AnotherFoo\n"; }
};
```

The alternative is to parametrize the different implementations of an interface. This time, the class template depends on both a **template-template parameter** and a non-type parameter

```
template<template<int> class F, int X>
class BarInterface
:
    public enable_down_cast< F<X> >
{
private:
    // dependent name now in scope
    using enable_down_cast< F<X> >::self;

public:
    // interface
    void bar() { self()->do_bar(); }    

protected:
    // disable deletion of Derived* through Base*
    // enable deletion of Base* through Derived*
    ~BarInterface() = default; // C++11 only, use ~BarInterface() {} in C++98/03
};
```

The implementation is then another class template, which derives from the interface with both itself and the non-type parameter as arguments

```
template< int X >
class BarImpl
:
    public BarInterface< BarImpl, X > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class BarInterface< ::BarImpl, X >;
    void do_bar() { std::cout << X << "\n"; }    
};
```

This is how you call them:

```
int main()
{
    FooImpl f1;         
    AnotherFooImpl f2;
    BarImpl< 1 > b1;
    BarImpl< 2 > b2;

    f1.foo();
    f2.foo();
    b1.bar();
    b2.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

The classes in your question don't quite fit into this general pattern. If you might want to give `Derived` some CRTP-like behavior, then you can either do

```
class Derived1
: 
   public CRTP< Derived1 > 
{

};

template<int I>
class Derived2
: 
   public CRTPInt< Derived2, I >
{

};
```

**UPDATE**: Based on the discussion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11571808/819272, I discovered that the original answer only compiled on Visual Studio 2010, but not on gcc because of some Microsoft-specific, non-portable features. E.g. the `self()` function from `enable_down_cast` is a (template) dependent name in its derived classes, and therefore not visible without explicit `using` directives. Furthermore, I have added defaulted destructors with the right level of protection. Finally, I have renamed my original class `enable_crtp` to `enable_down_cast` because that is precisely what it does: manually enable for static polymporphism what the compiler does automatically for dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the derived 2 solution. I'm putting together a modular camera object that allows policies to mix and match lenses, dollies, etc. I'd like to be able to specify a zoom lens as the focal min and focal max, i.e. Camera<Zoom<24,70>>, but the lens in return needs access to camera to call functions of other modules. (Actually in the lens case it does not, but in Dollies and Heads they do.)

Comment: @Tavison For policy-based designs you do not always need CRTP. E.g. you can directly derive from each policy: `template<typename ZoomPolicy, typename DolliesPolicy> class Camera: public ZoomPolicy, pubic DolliesPlicy {};` Instead, you can then let each `ConcreteZoomPolicy` derive from a specific `ZoomInterface` etc.

Comment: @Tavison To continue, you could make `template<typename Impl, int Min, int Max> class ZoomInterface: private enable_crpt< Impl<Min, Max> > {};` and then have implementations like `template<int Min, int Max> class ZoomImpl: public ZoomInterface< ZoomImpl, Min, Max > {};`. Then you could have a `Camera< ZoomImpl<24, 70> >`

Comment: I'll play around with this and accept your answer when I get it working. I knew I needed another layer in there, but was not finding it.

Comment: This doesn't compile in VC10. I get these errors.
error C2923: 'F' : 'X' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '<unnamed-symbol>'
see declaration of 'X'
see reference to class template instantiation 'BarInterface<F,X>' being compiled
error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'BarImpl' does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'F'
see reference to class template instantiation 'BarImpl<X>' being compiled

Comment: cnt.

error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'BarImpl' does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'F'
error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'BarImpl' does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'F'
see reference to class template instantiation 'BarImpl<X>' being compiled
          with
          [
              X=1
          ]

Comment: @Tavison Sorry, I got the same error at first and edited it in my code, but I didn't correctly copy/paste it back to SO. Instead `template<typename> class F` it should of course read `template<int> class F` in the template parameter list of `BarInterface`.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't paying attention to that.