# This template code will not compile. Any ideas?

Tags: c++, templates

I got this code from rhalbersma, but it does not compile in VC 2010. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
template<typename Derived>
struct enable_crtp
{
private:
    // typedefs

    typedef enable_crtp Base;

public:
    // casting "down" the inheritance hierarchy
    Derived const* self() const
    {                   
        return static_cast<Derived const*>(this);
    }

    // write the non-const version in terms of the const version
    // Effective C++ 3rd ed., Item 3 (p. 24-25)
    Derived* self()
    {
        return const_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<Base const*>(this)->self());
    }      

protected:
    // disable deletion of Derived* through Base* 
    // enable deletion of Base* through Derived*
    ~enable_crtp()
    {
        // no-op
    }
};

template<typename FX>
class FooInterface
    :
    private enable_crtp< FX >
{
public:
    // interface
    void foo() { self()->do_foo(); }
};

class FooImpl
    :
    public FooInterface< FooImpl > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class FooInterface< FooImpl > ;
    void do_foo() { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
};

class AnotherFooImpl
    :
    public FooInterface< AnotherFooImpl > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class FooInterface< AnotherFooImpl >;
    void do_foo() { std::cout << "AnotherFoo\n"; }
};

template<template<typename> class F, int X>
class BarInterface
    :
    private enable_crtp< F<X> >
{
// interface
void bar() { self()->do_bar(); }    
};

template< int X >
class BarImpl
    :
    public BarInterface< BarImpl, X > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class BarInterface< ::BarImpl, X >;
    void do_bar() { std::cout << X << "\n"; }    
};

int main()
{
    FooImpl f1;         
    AnotherFooImpl f2;

    BarImpl< 1 > b1;
    BarImpl< 2 > b2;

    f1.foo();
    f2.foo();
    b1.bar();
    b2.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can not compile, sometimes is caused by environment settings. Maybe missing 3rd party library in VS2010.

Comment: You have multiple issues and are more likely receive help if you narrow your use case down a bit. Remove either Foo or Bar and concentrate on the problems one at a time. Include the error messages you get from the compiler so those who don't have immediate access to one can lend assistance as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I remake this code for GCC-4.4 and can't check for VC 2010.
Errors:

1. Wrong template class declaration in template BarInterface -- replace `typename` to `int`:
   `template<template<int> class F, int X>
   class BarInterface`
2. Set public to `foo()` and `bar()` method:
   `public:
   void xxx() { self()->do_xxx(); }`
3. Set public for base class `enable_crtp<FX>` in classes `BarInterface` and `FooInterface`:
   `public enable_crtp< FX >`
4. Add scope specification for calling `self()` method in `foo()` and `bar()` methods:
   `void xxx() { enable_crtp<FX>::self()->do_xxx(); }`

And finally I get working code:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct enable_crtp
{
private:
// typedefs

    typedef enable_crtp Base;

public:
    // casting "down" the inheritance hierarchy
    Derived const* self() const
    {                   
        return static_cast<Derived const*>(this);
    }

    // write the non-const version in terms of the const version
    // Effective C++ 3rd ed., Item 3 (p. 24-25)
    Derived* self()
    {
        return const_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<Base const*>(this)->self());
    }      

protected:
    // disable deletion of Derived* through Base* 
    // enable deletion of Base* through Derived*
    ~enable_crtp()
    {
        // no-op
    }
};

template<typename FX>
class FooInterface
    :
    public enable_crtp< FX >
{
public:
    // interface
    void foo() { enable_crtp<FX>::self()->do_foo(); }
};

class FooImpl
    :
    public FooInterface< FooImpl > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class FooInterface< FooImpl > ;
    void do_foo() { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
};

class AnotherFooImpl
    :
    public FooInterface< AnotherFooImpl > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class FooInterface< AnotherFooImpl >;
    void do_foo() { std::cout << "AnotherFoo\n"; }
};

template<template<int> class F, int X>
class BarInterface
    :
    public enable_crtp< F<X> >
{
public:
// interface
void bar() { enable_crtp< F<X> >::self()->do_bar(); }    
};

template< int X >
class BarImpl
    :
    public BarInterface< BarImpl, X > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class BarInterface< ::BarImpl, X >;
    void do_bar() const { std::cout << X << "\n"; }    
};

int main()
{
    FooImpl f1;         
    AnotherFooImpl f2;

    BarImpl< 1 > b1;
    BarImpl< 2 > b2;

    f1.foo();
    f2.foo();
    b1.bar();
    b2.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I spaced on the int / typename thing.

Comment: @Lex +1 this answer. In my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11547473/819272 to the original question by Tavison, I had indeed used some Microsoft specific features such as dependent name lookup in base classes. This is now fixed in the answer. Thanks for your corrections. (I didn't notice this thread until now.)

Answer (score 1):

```
template<template<typename> class F, int X>
class BarInterface
: 
private enable_crtp< F<X> >
{
// interface
void bar() { self()->do_bar(); }    
};
```

i guess

```
    template<template<int > class F, int X>
class BarInterface
: 
private enable_crtp< F<X> >
{
// interface
void bar() { self()->do_bar(); }    
};
```

then you need fix two error about access private member function

```
template<typename Derived>
struct enable_crtp
{
private:
    // typedefs

    typedef enable_crtp Base;

public:
    // casting "down" the inheritance hierarchy
    Derived const* self() const
    {                   
        return static_cast<Derived const*>(this);
    }

    // write the non-const version in terms of the const version
    // Effective C++ 3rd ed., Item 3 (p. 24-25)
    Derived* self()
    {
        return const_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<Base const*>(this)->self());
    }      

protected:
    // disable deletion of Derived* through Base* 
    // enable deletion of Base* through Derived*
    ~enable_crtp()
    {
        // no-op
    }
};

template<typename FX>
class FooInterface
    :
    private enable_crtp< FX >
{
public:
    // interface
    void foo() { self()->do_foo(); }
};

class FooImpl
    :
    public FooInterface< FooImpl > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class FooInterface< FooImpl > ;
    void do_foo() { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
};

class AnotherFooImpl
    :
    public FooInterface< AnotherFooImpl > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class FooInterface< AnotherFooImpl >;
    void do_foo() { std::cout << "AnotherFoo\n"; }
};

template<template<int > class F, int X>
class BarInterface
    :
    private enable_crtp< F<X> >
{
    // interface
public: void bar() { self()->do_bar(); }    
};

template< int X >
class BarImpl
    :
    public BarInterface< BarImpl, X > 
{
private:
    // implementation
    friend class BarInterface< ::BarImpl, X >;
    void do_bar() { std::cout << X << "\n"; }    
};

int main()
{
    FooImpl f1;         
    AnotherFooImpl f2;

    BarImpl< 1 > b1;
    BarImpl< 2 > b2;

    f1.foo();
    f2.foo();
    b1.bar();
    b2.bar();

    return 0;
}
```