# CRTP and template template?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp, template-templates

I would like to do CRTP for template classes and I want the abstract base class to know about the template parameters of the derived classes.

I tried this but it does not work :

```
template<template<class T, unsigned int TDIM> class TCRTP> class NAbstract
{
    T _data[TDIM];
};

template<typename T, unsigned int TDIM> class NArray : NAbstract< NArray<T, TDIM> >
{

};

template<typename T, unsigned int TDIM> class NVector : NAbstract< NVector<T, TDIM> >
{

};
```

g++ 4.6.2 tells me :

```
main.cpp|5|error: 'T' does not name a type|
main.cpp|8|error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class T, unsigned int TDIM> class TCRTP> class NAbstract'|
main.cpp|8|error:   expected a class template, got 'NArray<T, TDIM>'|
main.cpp|13|error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class T, unsigned int TDIM> class TCRTP> class NAbstract'|
main.cpp|13|error:   expected a class template, got 'NVector<T, TDIM>'|
```

What is the problem and what would be the good solution for a such thing ?

Comment: You cannot use `T` which is inside template template, i.e. `template<class T, unsigned int TDIM>`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11547473/819272 for a related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to specialize the template partially:

```
template <typename> struct NAbstract;

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
struct NAbstract<NArray<T, N>>
{
    T _data[N];
    // ...
};
```

Alternatively:

```
template <template <typename, unsigned int> class Container,
          typename T, unsigned int N>
struct NAbstract<Container<T, N>>
{
    T _data[N];
    // ...
};
```

Comment: In my case, the interest of CRTP is that I will be able to define like 200 functions for all derived type once for all in the NAbstract class. If I specialize the template, the advantage of CRTP disappear (but maybe I'm wrong and I haven't understood your example).

Comment: @Vincent: OK, I'm adding a slightly different partial specialization that might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Below demonstrates your code after fixing errors:

```
template<class T, unsigned int TDIM, template<class, unsigned int> class TCRTP>
class NAbstract
{
  T _data[TDIM];
};

template<typename T, unsigned int TDIM>
class NArray : NAbstract< T, TDIM, NArray >
{
};

template<typename T, unsigned int TDIM>
class NVector : NAbstract< T, TDIM, NVector >
{
};
```

You cannot use `template template` parameters. In fact, compiler simply ignores them.
e.g. From your original code, `T` and `TDIM` are ignored in below line:

```
template<template<class T, unsigned int TDIM> class TCRTP> class NAbstract
                       ^^^              ^^^^  // <--- ignored
```

Comment: Passing `T` and `TDIM` independently is a source of unnecessary errors. However, passing the derived classes without template arguments is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with traits. Then, you don't need a template template parameter for `NAbstract`.

```
template<class TCRTP>
class NAbstract {
    typename TCRTP::value_type data_[TCRTP::DIM];
};

template<typename T, unsigned int TDIM>
struct NTraits {
    typedef T value_type;
    enum { DIM = TDIM };
};

template<typename T, unsigned int TDIM>
struct NArray : NAbstract< NTraits<T, TDIM> > {
};

template<typename T, unsigned int TDIM>
struct NVector : NAbstract< NTraits<T, TDIM> > {
};
```

Comment: This code produces the following error : (with g++ 4.6.2) : error: no type named 'value_type' in 'class NArray<double, 3u>' (when I declare a NArray<double, 3>)

Comment: @Vincent: My bad. NVector cannot expose its traits until after that line of code. Edited with a fixed version, but the usefulness depends on what you want out of `NAbstract`.